# How to add a jar file in my library project?

Tags: android, jar, numberpicker

Im my app I want to use this NumberPicker:

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

I've copied the .jar file from this project, build the path in Eclipse, and imported it at my MainActivity class.

My xml file has the following code:

```
<net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But I am getting this error at LogCat:

```
11-21 15:12:41.486: E/AndroidRuntime(6315): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxxx.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #138: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker
11-21 15:12:41.486: E/AndroidRuntime(6315): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #138: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker
11-21 15:12:41.486: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker.<init>(NumberPicker.java:532)
```

What is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you placed the new jar in the lib folder?

Comment: Yes. It is aleady in my lib folder.

Comment: How did you finally solve it? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your lib form java build path. just right click the properties and then find java build path to add your jar.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
 <net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker
  android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout
```

Try this.

Comment: I think you are having error while inflating your view, Please add more code.

Comment: @user1771682 please specify in what package your creating your custom view.

Comment: I think, the problem is this:

Android 4.0 NumberPicker backported to 2.1
Requires JakeWhartons NineOldAndroids library. It is included as a jar, but also available at: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids
Probably has to be built against API level 15
To use this library, it's required that 4 attributes are added to your theme. Check the sample app on how this is done.

Comment: No I am trying fix the themes.

Comment: have you added xmlns:custom to your parent layout?

Comment: No. How can I do this? Eclipse shows this warning: Unused namespace custom.

Comment: My xml is already this way. And Eclipse show the warning: Unused namespace custom. And the app does not works.

Comment: can you please specify in code where you are getting this warnings?

Comment: I've already fixed my project. I just added a libray which should be used in the project. Thank you